# Multiple Notification android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm building an app in which the user puts multiple alarms at specific date and time and takes a notification for each alarm, when the time comes. For each notification there is a different id number. My problem is that when I put 2 alarms, the newer will work but the older one won't. It's like the second alarm kills the first..According to some tutorials and forums,given that I use unique id's that shouldn't happen, right?

Here is my code of Notification Service:

```
    DataBase db = new DataBase(getApplicationContext());        
    String message = db.getTask(id);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "You have message", System.currentTimeMillis());   

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "You 've got something to do", message, pendingIntent);

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);


}
```

Database is using the id's to get the right messages for each notification..And it works fine..So, I think there is no problem with the id. Any ideas?? Could anything be wrong with my manifest file??

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may have the same problem, I found the solution. Actually the problem was at my alarm manager code. I didn't set the ids as a parameter in the pending intent, like I do in the above code. Now it works fine.